# proc call returning type mismatch error from import but not when include

Tags: nim-lang

I have a procedure that I am using as a constructor, to construct a custom object type, a "Scene" object. When I import the procedure from another module, I get this compiler error:

> main.nim(44, 43) Error: type mismatch: got (name: string, seq[SceneObject], slc: SceneLifeCycle)
>   but expected one of:
>   proc newScene(name: string; sceneObjects: seq[SceneObject]; slc: SceneLifeCycle): Scene

However, when I move that same procedure's definition over to the same file from which I'm calling it from, it works perfectly. What am I doing wrong in importing, or is there an inconsistency in Nim's import and export behavior concerning custom object types? Also, simply including the file fixes this issue.

```
# src/game_types.nim - where I am storing type definitions

SceneLifeCycleProc* = proc()

SceneObject* = ref object
  tags*: seq[string]
  active*: bool
  visible*: bool
  x, y: float

Scene* = ref object
  name*: string
    sceneObjects*: seq[SceneObject]
    onRegister*: SceneLifeCycleProc
    onEnter*: SceneLifeCycleProc
    onUpdate*: SceneLifeCycleProc
    onRender*: SceneLifeCycleProc
    onExit*: SceneLifeCycleProc
    onDestroy*: SceneLifeCycleProc


# src/scene_managment.nim - file exporting newScene from

include game_types

proc newScene* ( name: string, sceneObjects: seq[SceneObject], slc: 
  SceneLifeCycle): Scene =
  new result
  result.name = name
  result.sceneObjects = sceneObjects
  result.onRegister = slc[0]
  result.onEnter = slc[1]
  result.onUpdate = slc[2]
  result.onRender = slc[3]
  result.onExit = slc[4]
  result.onDestroy = slc[5]
```

and main.nim, which doesn't seem to work via importing of newScene:

```
# src/main.nim

include game_types
import scene_management

# throws type mismatch error
let titleScene = newScene(
  "title",
  newSeq[SceneObject](4),
  [registerTitleScene.SceneLifeCycleProc,
  enterTitleScene.SceneLifeCycleProc,
  updateTitleScene.SceneLifeCycleProc,
  renderTitleScene.SceneLifeCycleProc,
  exitTitleScene.SceneLifeCycleProc,
  destroyTitleScene.SceneLifeCycleProc]
 )
```

but with the newScene procedure defined within main.nim, it works great:

```
# src/main.nim - this works, and I don't know why importing doesn't:
include game_types

# defined in the same file
proc newScene ( name: string, sceneObjects: seq[SceneObject], slc: 
  SceneLifeCycle): Scene =
  new result
  result.name = name
  result.sceneObjects = sceneObjects
  result.onRegister = slc[0]
  result.onEnter = slc[1]
  result.onUpdate = slc[2]
  result.onRender = slc[3]
  result.onExit = slc[4]
  result.onDestroy = slc[5]


# no compiler error
let titleScene = newScene(
  "title",
  newSeq[SceneObject](4),
  [registerTitleScene.SceneLifeCycleProc,
  enterTitleScene.SceneLifeCycleProc,
  updateTitleScene.SceneLifeCycleProc,
  renderTitleScene.SceneLifeCycleProc,
  exitTitleScene.SceneLifeCycleProc,
  destroyTitleScene.SceneLifeCycleProc]
)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: avoid using `include`.

Long answer: The problem is that you're including `game_types` into different modules so depending on the module they end up declared in different namespaces and thus are different types. E.g., your first example calls `newScene` passing `main.SceneLyfeCycle` to it, but `newScene` accepts `scene_managment.SceneLyfeCycle`. Your second example works, because `newScene` accepts `main.SceneLyfeCycle` and you're passing exactly that to it.